# Use Excel VBA to open Word document and use Find method to find a string and replace all to another string, it doesn't take effect

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

**My objective:**
Use Excel VBA to open Word document and use Find method to find a string and replace all to another string

**My input file content:** ("C:\Temp\testWord1.doc")

[image]

**Code in Excel VBA:**

```
Private Sub testReplaceWordFile()
    Dim oWrdApp
    Dim doc1
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set oWrdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set doc1 = oWrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Temp\testWord1.doc", ReadOnly:=False)
    
    Debug.Print doc1.Content.Text
    With doc1.Content.Find
        .Text = "PsWD"
        .Replacement.Text = "Test"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Debug.Print "==========================="
    Debug.Print doc1.Content.Text
    
    doc1.Save
    doc1.Close
    oWrdApp.Quit
    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "done"
    Else
        Debug.Print "error:" & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**Problem:**

1. My expectation is: after execute the code, all "PsWD" will be placed with "Test". We should also see the change of "doc1.Content.Text" before and after executing ".Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll"
2. Actual is: no change on the doc file, the code ".Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll" doesn't take effect

**Help required:**
Please help to advise what's the issue of the code. Thanks.

Comment: With late binding, Excel doesn't know the Word Enumerations, eg [`wdFindContinue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfindwrap) and [`wdReplaceAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdreplace).  Replace them with their actual values, or ayour own Enumeration.

Comment: Big thanks @Chris Neilsen. The solution works.